# Ошибка при очистке и построении  Maven + Netbeans

Tags: maven, java, netbeans

При попытке совершения действия выводит следующее:

> cd D:ProjectsKZTOK-Web-UI;
> "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27"
> ""C:\Program Files\NetBeans
> 7.0.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat"" -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Ptest clean install Scanning for projects... The
> build could not read 1 project ->
> [Help 1]
>      The project kz.erp.tais.web.ui:TOK-Web-UI:1.0
> (D:ProjectsKZTOK-Web-UIpom.xml)
> has 1 error
>     'repositories.repository.id' must be unique:
> maven2-repository.dev.java.net ->
> http://download.java.net/maven/1/ vs
> http://download.java.net/maven/2/ @
> kz.erp.tais.tok:project:1,
> D:ProjectsKZTOKpom.xml, line 120,
> column 17
>
> To see the full stack trace of the
> errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X
> switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors
> and possible solutions, please read
> the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же все в ошибке написано

> 'repositories.repository.id' must be unique: maven2-repository.dev.java.net -> http://download.java.net/maven/1/ vs http://download.java.net/maven/2/ @ kz.erp.tais.tok:project:1, D:ProjectsKZTOKpom.xml, line 120, column 17

Похоже, `id` репозиториев неуникальны. Если это не так, то приведите сюда текст `pom.xml` на 120±10 строке.